# Don't display taxonomy if empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm using the following code to display my custom post taxonomies:

```
function display_post_taxonomies( $content ) {

if( is_single() ) { 
    $args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );     
    $output = 'objects';        
    $operator = 'and';      
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator );

    if( $taxonomies ) {     
        $content .= '<div class="taxonomy_container">';         
        foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {           
            $args = array(
                            'orderby'               => 'name',
                            'echo'                  => false,
                            'taxonomy'              => $taxonomy->name,
                            'title_li'              => '<span class="taxonomy_title">' . __( $taxonomy->labels->name, 'your-themes-text-domain' ) . '</span>',
                            'show_option_none'      => __( 'No ' . $taxonomy->labels->name, 'your-themes-text-domain' )
                        );
            $content .= '<ul>' . wp_list_categories( $args ) . '</ul>';             
        }           
        $content .= '</div>';       
    }
}   
return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'display_post_taxonomies' );
```

This works fine, except there are some cases where I don't have anything in my custom taxonomy. In those cases, I don't want there to be anything displayed at all, i.e., No taxonomy title or default 'no terms' message.

I can get rid of the 'no terms' message by simply setting `show_option_none` to `false`, but that leaves the name of the taxonomy there.

What I really need is an `if` statement similar to

```
if($taxonomy => 'objects'){
    //$args & &content arrays
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Taxonomies are not the target which you are looking for. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomies/

Ultimately you need terms inside taxonomies:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

And terms have an option to

'hide_empty' => true,

Answer (score 1):

What you need is set the `show_option_none` to a string easily recognizable and then add the result of `wp_list_categories` to the content only if it it does not contain that string..

So your foreach loop shoul look somethinlg like

```
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {           
  $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'echo' => false,
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name,
    'title_li' => '<span class="taxonomy_title">' . __( $taxonomy->labels->name, 'your-themes-text-domain' ) . '</span>',
    'show_option_none' => '%%NOCAT%%'
  );
  $list = wp_list_categories( $args );
  $empty = (bool) substr_count( strip_tags($list), '%%NOCAT%%');
  $content .= ! $empty ? '<ul>' . $list . '</ul>' : '';              
}
```

In this way if your custom tax has no terms the result of `wp_list_categories` is not added to the html output.

---

### Additional suggestions

Just few days ago I experienced an issue using something like

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'display_post_taxonomies' );
```

because some SEO plugins use `get_the_excerpt` to fill the meta description in the `<head>` section of the page.
Problem is that `get_the_excerpt`, when there is no manual excerpt for post, call `wp_trim_excerpt` and this function fires `the_content` hook. Result: you will find the list of your taxonomy in the head of your page: that's bad.

Also you should note that `'the_content'` hook can be fired not only in main query, so if you have some secondary queries on sidebar or footer your function will be called again there: that's bad.

What I suggest is where you have

```
if( is_single() ) {
```

replace with

```
if( is_single() && did_action('loop_start') ) {
```

This prevent function run in the `<head>` section.

After that, remove the filter befor return the content, in this way you are sure the filter run once, so

```
return $content;
```

became

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'display_post_taxonomies' );
return $content;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked :/

Comment: There is no change, it still shows the empty titles just as before.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer edited the answer. Tested and worked for me.

Comment: Putting the did_action stuff just makes my custom taxonomy not show up at all. I don't have any SEO plugins installed and my taxonomy is not coming up in my head.

Comment: Sorry @sanjaypoyzer right hook is `did_action('loop_start')`. It doesn't hurt and if if future you want to add seo plugin you'll not have problems. Anyway, my solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

Use get_the_term_list instead of the_terms which return the terms list instead of printing, so output can be used for both purpose.
Check the answer: [Display taxonomy term only if there's a value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221264/display-taxonomy-term-only-if-theres-a-value)