# Display taxonomy term only if there's a value

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a post type which I want to add some taxonomy values (tags)

Example Post Type One

1. **City**: London, Paris
2. **Color**: Red, Yellow
3. **Language**:

In the example above, Language doesn't have any value, therefore, I want to hide it.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$lang= get_terms( 'lang' );
if ( !empty( $lang)) {
     echo '<li><strong>Language:</strong>';
    the_terms( $post->ID, 'lang', ' ', ', ' );
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

But **Language** will still appear even though I don't add any tags on it.

Comment: `the_terms( $post->ID, 'city', ' ', ', ' )` You are displaying terms from `city` not `lang`.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't the problem. Just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) return all the terms in the taxonomy regardless of the current post.
So if current post does not have **lang** terms still this condition `if ( !empty( $lang))` will be `true` thus it will display the text **Language**.

Use [`get_the_term_list`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) instead of `the_terms` which return the terms list instead of printing, so output can be used for both purpose.

Example:-

```
$lang = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'lang', ' ', ', ' );
if ( !empty( $lang)) {
    echo '<li><strong>Language:</strong>' . $lang . '</li>';
}
```

> Note: Recommended approach is to use `get_the_ID()` instead of global
>   `$post->ID`

Comment: The first answer (above) will sometimes still display the taxonomy even without value. So I think you have the best answer. And thanks for the note though I'm not sure why get_the_ID() is better. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Check this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112400/32475

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function returns (array/int/WP_Error) list of WP_Term instances and their children. Will return WP_Error, if any of $taxonomies do not exist.

So you need no modify your if condition to following

```
if ( ! empty( $lang ) && ! is_wp_error( $lang ) ){
 //your code....
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: This one works great but the answer below also works (get_the_term_list) . So now I don't know what to use. The only difference though is that when I haven't registered the taxonomy yet, the answer below displays an error. Your answer doesn't display anything. So I think it's better (?).

Comment: I just focus on if condition and return type of get_terms() function. and you decided which is help you most. :)